# Query where my table timestamp is <= 1 min from current timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server

Due to some activity in my project I want to run this query in some frequency and check "where my query can fetch table timestamp is <= 1 min from current timestamp"

SQL Query to check the updated data in the table.

Comment: Seems you are very new to StackOverflow and you are asking the question for the first time. 
Please provide the sample data, an existing query that you have written so far, and where you need the help so that people can help you.

Comment: Your question appears to be missing your query. Also what research have you done on how to schedule a query? What options have you considered?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Even though your question is incomplete, you haven't provided your existing table structure or any queries. I'm just giving you some generic solution here which should work as long as you can convert that based on your specific need.

so, you are trying to get the difference of two-time values in minutes

- Time that record was saved
- Current Time

If you have a table : LogRecords with below fields:

- LogId
- LogMessage
- LogTimestamp

then you would write your query to pull last-minute logs as :

```
select * from LogRecords
where DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LogTimestamp , GETDATE()) <= 1
```

I haven't tested this code but it should be 99% similar if it won't work. Please try and let me know.

Comment: Be aware the where clause is non-[sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable). To make it sargable, express it as a range comparison, something like `WHERE LogTimestamp >= {DateTimeOneMinuteAgo} AND   LogTimestamp <= getDate()`